# If I have a UITabBarController, how can I pop back to the initial view controller in a tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBarController with three tabs. I want to programmatically put the first tab back to its initial view controller. It uses a navigation controller to have hierarchical navigation.

My issue is that I can't simply call `popToRootViewController` on `tabBarController.viewControllers[0]` as that view controller could have modally presented more navigation controllers, where it would only bring back to the original modal. At which point I'd need to call `dismissViewController`, then `popToRootViewController` again an unknown amount of times.

Is there a way to more or less say `tabBarController.popAllViewControllers`?